# Scopes and claims in IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have implemented IdentityServer4 in ASP.NET core with one application as Identity server and second one as client. I have couple of queries 
 1. I want to add roles to the profile information returned.
 2. What are scopes there for ?

can someone provide a fair idea ?

Answer (score 1):

To add roles, check out the IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity nuget package.  See [Using ASP.NET Core Identity](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html).

Scopes are used to create a relationship between ApiResources and Clients.  Rather than say, associated the name of a client api (e.g. AccountingApi) to an ApiResource, we associated the client api to a scope (e.g. internalApis) and then associated the same scope to the ApiResource.